# Why is my local video file path within the document directory not working after some time? [Swift]

Tags: swift, url

I have a custom video recording view controller, in which I save using a URL:

Sample URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/802497BB-8413-4245-B33A-708EF8DD9CAF/Documents/FA6AF78A-2692-4CC8-8BE2-7F18140C3C98.mp4

The URL is generated using these functions:

```
// Gets the directory that the video is stored in
    func getPathDirectory() -> URL {
        // Searches a FileManager for paths and returns the first one
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentDirectory
    }

    func generateURL() -> URL? {
        let path = getPathDirectory().appendingPathComponent(NSUUID().uuidString + ".mp4")
        return path
    }
```

I then replay the video once in a separate playback controller, and it works no problem. I have included it right below:

```
import AVFoundation

class VideoPlaybackController: UIViewController {
    
    let avPlayer = AVPlayer()
    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
    
    var videoURL: URL!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
//        print("VideoPlaybackController: \(videoURL!)")
        
        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayerLayer.frame = view.bounds
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        videoView.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)
        
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: self.videoURL as URL)
        avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
        
        avPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

While the video works, after some time, the video cannot be replayed, even though I saved it within the document directory. I downloaded the xcappdata and looked within the contents of the app, and saw that the video file is still there, so I am confused as to why the video is not available after some time.

Is there something that I am missing? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I guess you are saving the whole file path. Your application is sandboxed and the path will change every time you launch your app. You need to save only it’s directory and name and reconstruct your URL.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you!